# Phonegap Geolocation in App Store not working

Tags: geolocation, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, store, phonegap

i have build my own app and published it to the app store.
Its available on store, but there is a problem.
Im working with Geolocation and google maps.

Here is a link to Phonegap's Geolocation:

[phonegap geolocation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html)

When i start my app on Phonegap app emulator, i get asked to accept the geolocation, so the app has access to it.

[image: phonegap app]

It works fine! i get my longitude and latitude and can work with it.

But the same app, downloaded from the app store, doesn't work.
I don't get asked to allow geolocation, and even on settings there is not a sign to me where i can turn it on.

Screenshot from the app, google maps, with lat & long = 0 (default).
Aka no geolocation working.

[image: appstore]

Anyone facing the same issue? Any ideas?
greets Luca

Answer (score 1):

Edit your config.xml

add this line of code

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~4.0.1" />

<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: Not sure if working, will need some time.
But thanks for the answer. Hope that will do it #thumb